# Run Adobe software in Docker?

Tags: vmware, docker, adobe, photoshop

I'm new to Linux, I'm a web developer and I often need to use Photoshop for slicing, or other adobe software, but unfortunately they don't run natively in Linux.
I tried several ways to run them:

1. **Wine** - which is the worst tool I've ever worked with, crashing, working slowly etc.
2. **VMware Workstation Player** which also is not a great solution; Windows 10 works very slowly in it, though my PC is pretty strong (4ghz, 16gb ram, ssd).

I wonder if Docker can be installed and can run Photoshop, Lightroom and other software that doesn't support Linux.

Or may be there are some other solutions that I don't know?

Comment: Nope, otherwise, you'd probably know about it. ...and since it's not about Ubuntu, it's off topic.

Comment: Docker provides containers but not VMs. The containers offer isolation but not virtualization. The host and container OSs must be the same. -- You can use Windows Containers (to run windows applications) on Windows, but not on Linux. -- you may check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158596/can-windows-containers-be-hosted-on-linux

Comment: [jgautheron/dockerfiles](https://github.com/jgautheron/dockerfiles/tree/master/photoshop) is Adobe Photoshop CS2 for Windows in a container, running on Linux thanks to Wine, so it's clearly on topic although it doesn't answer your question because you'll get the same problems with Wine that you mentioned in 1. crashing, working slowly, etc. The same goes for Ubuntu Studio, you get the same problems with Wine no matter what you package it in. So the next thing is to purchase an improved alternative to Wine like Crossover which gives Photoshop CS6 a Limited Functionality rating.

Comment: You've tried wine 2.15 version, didn't you? I'm asking because Ubuntu, especially LTS, tends to have outdated software *(unless you manually enable PPAs)*, and if you tried wine-1.6 or so, it's like you didn't try Wine. It have had [a lot of versions, fixes, and features since then](https://www.winehq.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wine provices a compatibility layer that translates windows system calls in to POSIX system calls that Ubuntu can understand.

Virtualbox provides emulations of a system environment that allows you to run another operating system. This is still the preferred way to run original software in an expected operating system. Obviously both solutions are slower than using software natively. In my experience, Windows 10 in a virtualbox on Ubuntu runs slower than Windows 7 does, but that might depend on my hardware.

Docker provides an abstraction layer using kernel virtualization, but it does not provide windows system calls, so it will not help you run windows software that does not run on Ubuntu without Docker.

Answer (score 2):

Arkadi

I understand where you are coming from as I was so used to using Photoshop and Illustrator and Light room that I was not making a change to Linux because of it. I have now converted to Linux for about a year and believe me Inkscape is a solid vector software. If you are used to Illustrator keyboard shortcuts you can change the shortcuts so it matches Illustrator shortcuts. Especially the new version they have out is really cool.

As far as Photoshop I would say GIMP is just as bad ass, just needs some getting used to. Take some tutorials and do some easy step by step instructions play with it a bit. Everyone is different but in order for this to work for me I had to not completely commit so I didn't want to us VMs to be able to use Adobe CC.

Lightroom check out a program Dark table much much much better then Light room i mean Dark table is the shit, once you get used to this program you will never pay adobe 50 dollars a month.

I do have a question for you my brother, are you Armenian, because you look Armenian. Not that it matters but I too am Armenian, Georgian and Armenian people are always brothers so I hope I was able to help a brother.

Best Regards

Comment: Please don't post your email address and add signatures to your answer.